# Set new version number and build all at once in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to set a version number and build a project in Maven, but the artifact appears to be the old version, even though the version number is successfully set during the process. The command is:

```
versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.1 clean compile package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -U
```

The output starts off like this:

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyLibraries 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.1:set (default-cli) @ SharedLibraries ---
[INFO] Searching for local aggregator root...
[INFO] Local aggregation root: C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\workspaces\MyWorkspace\MyProjectRoot
[INFO] Processing com.mycompanies:MyLibraries
[INFO]     Updating project com.myCompany:MyLibraries
[INFO]         from version 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
Props: {project.artifactId=MyLibraries, project.version=1.0.1, project.groupId=com.myCompany}
Props: {project.artifactId=MyLibraries, project.version=1.0.1, project.groupId=com.myCompany}
Props: {project.artifactId=MyLibraries, project.version=1.0.1, project.groupId=com.myCompany}
Props: {project.artifactId=MyLibraries, project.version=1.0.1, project.groupId=com.myCompany}
[INFO] 
[INFO] Processing com.myCompany:Assembly
[INFO]     Updating parent com.myCompany:MyLibraries
[INFO]         from version 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
```

But then later:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyLibraries 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the version number of the final jar is 1.0.0.

Is it possible to update the version and build the project in one command, or do I need two commands: one to update the version and another to build?

I'm doing this in RAD (based on the Eclipse platform) so I'd rather avoid having to click twice for two run configurations, if possible.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use release plugin for updating the versions after release?

Comment: @khmarbaise: We're not yet at the point of connecting Maven with source control - would the release plugin do what I want without needing to connect to source control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are facing in that case is that if you call `mvn versions:set ... clean package` the pom files haven been loaded into memory (reactor) and will be later used by the package lifecycle but with the call of the goal of the versions-maven-plugin you are changing the pom files on hard disk. So in other words you need to have different calls to succeed.

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.1
mvn clean package
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I tried `versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.1  ; clean compile package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -U` but then maven complained that `;` was not a valid goal.

Comment: Maybe you meant `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.1 ; mvn clean compile package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -U`? Though mind you, whether this will work depends on the console you're using - the standard Windows console won't do what you want it to but something like bash will.

Comment: @blalasaadri: I'm running it Eclipse Run Configuration so I don't actually need to type `mvn`.

Comment: I'm not aware of any possibility of running consecutive maven jobs from one run configuration in eclipse and this seems to be what you need. One solution would probably be to have two separate run configurations... Not pretty but the best I can come up with as long as you want to use eclipse for building.

Comment: @blalasaadri: I suppose another option would be to have a batch script which does two calls to maven, and one Run Config to run the batch script... :/

Comment: Sure, you can do that. This would require a different type of run config of course but it should be possible.